# Set Rows to repeat at top when printing - Open XML and Excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, excel-2010, xlsx

I am trying to get the first 4 rows of an xlsx file to repeat at the top of each page when printed.  I am using the Open XML SDK to accomplish this.

My file is being generated by the SSRS execution web service as a filestream.  I then need to modify several layout and page settings (margins, page size, zoom, etc) before delivering the file to the user, as my users have very little Excel acumen.  All other settings I need to tweak are working correctly, so I have stripped out all of that code from this example.

When trying to set the repeating page headers using the code below, it executes with no errors.  However, when I try to open the file after executing the code, I am getting a corrupt file message and it won't open.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?!  It's driving me crazy!

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("C:\\" + filename, true))
{
WorkbookPart wbp = xl.WorkbookPart;

//-----------------------------------------
// repeat rows at top when printing
//-----------------------------------------
DefinedNames dn = new DefinedNames();
wbp.Workbook.Append(dn);
wbp.Workbook.Save();

DefinedNames definedNames = wbp.Workbook.Descendants<DefinedNames>().FirstOrDefault();
DefinedName n1 = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Titles", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U };
n1.Text = "alpha_sort_nc!$1:$4";
definedNames.Append(n1);
wbp.Workbook.Save();

xl.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**
@Duncan - After your comment, I try to find out root cause of file corrupt. It turns to be `SpreadsheetPinterSettings` is binary data in the document. Even adding the DefinedName `_xlnm.Print_Titles` to Spreadsheet; it doesn't have any effect during a **Print/Print Preview**.

It seems Open XML approach for handling spreadsheet printer settings is not helpful.

**Reflect code from Open XML SDK Productivity tool:** manually created Print Titles in MS Excel

```
// Adds child parts and generates content of the specified part.
public void CreateSpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart(SpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart part)
{
    GeneratePartContent(part);

}

// Generates content of part.
private void GeneratePartContent(SpreadsheetPrinterSettingsPart part)
{
    System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(partData);
    part.FeedData(data);
    data.Close();
}

#region Binary Data
private string partData = "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";

private System.IO.Stream GetBinaryDataStream(string base64String)
{
    return new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));
}

#endregion
```

**Alternate Approach [I'm not sure, you're interested :)]:** to due binary data part, code snippet for same using Interop. works perfectly!

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel._Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:/Users/jeeva/sample-excel-files/SampleExcel.xlsx");
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

xlWorksheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1";

xlWorkbook.Save();
xlWorkbook.Close();
```

---

Previous One:

These three lines not nesscary.

```
DefinedNames dn = new DefinedNames();
wbp.Workbook.Append(dn);
wbp.Workbook.Save();
```

To set Print Titles, DefinedName Text should be in format of **"Worksheet_name!Row_Range or Column_Range"**. 
For example: Row range: `Worksheet1!$1:$1` and Column range: `Worksheet1!$A:$A`

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:/Users/jeeva/sample-excel-files/SampleExcel.xlsx", true))
{             
    WorkbookPart wbp = xl.WorkbookPart;

    // Input for this program
    string name = "_xlnm.Print_Titles";
    string comment = "this is Print Titles for Sheet1";
    string text = "Sheet1!$1:$1";

    if (wbp.Workbook.DefinedNames == null) 
    {
        wbp.Workbook.DefinedNames = new DefinedNames();
    }                

    bool bFound = false;
    foreach (DefinedName d in wbp.Workbook.DefinedNames)
    {
        // if found overwrite existing defined name
        if (d.Name.Value.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            bFound = true;
            d.Text = text;
            d.Comment = comment;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!bFound) // if not found, add one
    {
        wbp.Workbook.DefinedNames.Append(getDefinedName(name, text, comment));
    }

    wbp.Workbook.Save();
    xl.Close();
}

private static DefinedName getDefinedName(string Name, string Text, string Comment)
{
    DefinedName dn = new DefinedName();
    dn.Text = Text;
    dn.Name = Name;
    dn.Comment = Comment;
    dn.LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)1U;
    dn.Xlm = true; // since its a special schema name
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, jeevatkm.  I tried your suggestion, and the problem is that the definedNames object is null if I remove the three lines that are not necessary, so the program crashes when I try to append the printTitles object to the definedNames collection.  However, my approach isn't working either, because the spreadsheet is corrupted when I try to open it.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Duncan - Updated the post for null check and I need a clarification, have you updated the Row range `alpha_sort_nc!$A$1:$F$1` value according to your excel file and then did you get file corrupted? Please let me know.

Comment: yes, I tried altering the row range as you suggested.  it boils down to this.  if the file already has a defined names collection and you try to edit it, everything works correctly.  however, when you try to add the collection and then append the repeated rows definedname to it, Excel bombs with an "Excel found unreadable characters" message.

Comment: you can test this by creating a new file with some dummy data in it and trying to run the C# code against it.  IT will bomb.  if you take the dummy file, and set the pages to repeat at top attribute, save the file, and then run the C# code against taht, it works correctly.  so the question is how to work around this?

Comment: @Duncan - done analysis on file corrupt issue and I have updated the post with analysis outcome, alternate, & code snippet which I tried at my end. I hope this helps!

Comment: I want to take a moment to thank you @jeevatkm for learning how to do a great answer! +1 for your effort here.

Comment: thanks very much jeevatkm.  I will try this in a couple hours when I have a minute.  I appreciate your time and diligence.

Comment: had a chance to test this morning, and this works!  @jeevatkm, thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Below code block solved my problem:

```
string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Content/Master-License-Export.xlsx";
                    var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true);           
                    WorkbookPart wbp = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

                    UInt32 localSheetId = 0;    //LocalSheetIds are 0-indexed.

                    var definedName = new DefinedName
                    {
                        Name = "_xlnm.Print_Titles",
                        LocalSheetId = localSheetId,
                        Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!${1}:${2}", "Master-License-Export", 1, 4)
                    };

                    if (wbp.Workbook.DefinedNames == null)
                    {
                        var definedNamesCol = new DefinedNames();
                        wbp.Workbook.Append(definedNamesCol);
                    }

                    wbp.Workbook.DefinedNames.Append(definedName);

                    wbp.Workbook.Save();
                    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is possible via [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sheet%20Tab&referringTitle=Documentation)

```
Worksheet.PageSetup.SetRowsToRepeatAtTop(1, 5);
```