# Setting DefinedNames in OpenXML to set Print Titles for all worksheets in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

My end aim is to programatically set Excel's "Print Titles" value of Page Setup for all worksheets in my document.

Initially I tried looking at using the `SpreadsheetPrintingParts` object ([based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13603989/1768779)) - however, that requires generating a base 64 string, which seemingly has to come from an exisiting file. (I am generating my spreadsheet from scratch.)

[This post](https://superuser.com/a/287622) then taught me that I could set "Print_Titles" as a defined name on the row I needed instead. I've been attempting to do that programatically, but this seems to corrupt all my files.

My code:

```
        var definedNamesCol = new DefinedNames();    //Create the collection
        var definedName = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Titles", Text = "\'SheetName\'!$2:$2", LocalSheetId = (UInt32) (_nextSheetId - 1) };       // Create a new range

        definedNamesCol.Append(definedName);                  // Add it to the collection

        _workbookPart.Workbook.Append(definedNamesCol);
```

I've also looked with the OpenXML productivity tool which suggests: (Essentially identical)

```
        DefinedNames definedNames1 = new DefinedNames();
        DefinedName definedName1 = new DefinedName(){ Name = "_xlnm.Print_Titles", LocalSheetId = (UInt32Value)0U };
        definedName1.Text = "\'SheetName\'!$2:$2";

        definedNames1.Append(definedName1)
```

I've also tried setting the `Xlm` property on `DefinedName` but the file then opens with an error that it contains Macro's in a Macro-Free file, which isn't what I think I want to do.

A (simplified) version of what I'm generating in workbook.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<x:workbook xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <x:sheets>
        <x:sheet name="ABBEY" sheetId="1" r:id="R2f5447238bc94fa4" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" />
    </x:sheets>
    <x:definedNames>
        <x:definedName name="_xlnm.Print_Titles" localSheetId="0">'SheetName'!$2:$2</x:definedName>
    </x:definedNames>
</x:workbook>
```

Is there a better way to approach the problem? Or is my intention right, and it's a misunderstanding of the method somewhere else?

Comment: Can you unzip the file you're creating and show the content of the `workbook.xml` file please? My hunch would be that the `definedNames` element is being added after the `calcPr` element but that's just a guess :)

Comment: @petelids: Added. My workbook.xml doesn't have a `calcPr` element, however I can see the version where I've added the DefinedName manually does. Would that be relevant?

Comment: I think that means my hunch was wrong. The `calcPr` element is optional so I *think* the above xml is valid. I'll do some more thinking. Orignally I thought it was related to something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398450/why-appending-autofilter-corrupts-my-excel-file-in-this-example/25410242#25410242)

Comment: @petelids: Got there...I'm afraid it turns out my example was probably overly simplified to show the problem. The above code was within a `CreateSheet` method, so was creating separate `definedNames` object for each sheet, when I actually should have had a single `definedNames` and many `definedName` tags within that. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the spec regardless...that helped!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Excel "Print Titles" with OpenXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238100/how-to-set-excel-print-titles-with-openxml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code was within a `CreateWorksheet` method, so was being called for each sheet. In the resulting `workbook.xml` file, this was then creating multiple `definedNames` objects, when there should only be a single `definedNames` object containing multiple `definedNames`.

I resolved the problem using this code:

```
        var definedName = new DefinedName() { Name = "_xlnm.Print_Titles", Text = "\'Sheet Name\'!$2:$2", LocalSheetId = (UInt32) (_nextSheetId - 1) };       // Create a new range

        if (_workbookPart.Workbook.DefinedNames == null)
        {
         var definedNamesCol = new DefinedNames();
        _workbookPart.Workbook.Append(definedNamesCol);
        }

        _workbookPart.Workbook.DefinedNames.Append(definedName);                  // Add it to the collection
```