# How to set Excel "Print Titles" with OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

How can I set the "Print Titles" property of a spreadsheet with OpenXML, to have a row show at the top of every printed page?

> [image: Print titles interface]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property is directly saved in the `SpreadsheetPrintingParts` object, however, this doesn't appear to be fully integrated into OpenXML as of yet, and requires passing a base64 string in to the variable. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13603989/1768779)) The content of this string appears to be tied to the machine the file is opened on, which didn't work for my implementation - I wasn't able to create a non-corrupt file through  `SpreadsheetPrintingParts.FeedData()`.

Instead, I found [this post](https://superuser.com/a/287622) which stated giving the row the defined name "Print_Titles" has the same effect. I was then able to create a defined name through OpenXML with the following code:

```
public void SetPrintTitleRows(int startRowIndex, int? endRowIndex = null)
        {
            var localSheetId = _localsheetId++;    //LocalSheetIds are 0-indexed.

            var definedName = new DefinedName
            {
                Name = "_xlnm.Print_Titles",
                LocalSheetId = localSheetId,
                Text = String.Format("\'{0}\'!${1}:${2}", _sheetName, startRowIndex, endRowIndex ?? startRowIndex)
            };

            if (_workbookPart.Workbook.DefinedNames == null)
            {
                var definedNamesCol = new DefinedNames();
                _workbookPart.Workbook.Append(definedNamesCol);
            }

            _workbookPart.Workbook.DefinedNames.Append(definedName);
        }
```

Points to note:

1. `DefinedName.LocalSheetId` is zero-indexed, as opposed to `Sheet.Id` which is 1-indexed
2. `DefinedNames` is once per workbook, but can contain multiple `DefinedName` objects for different sheets.