# Set Print Title in Excel using OpenTBS

Tags: php, excel, opentbs

I'm using PHP 5.3, OpenTBS version 1.7.6. Excel 2013.

In the Excel template I have set my title.

`[page layout -> print title -> sheet -> setting row to repeat at top]`

However, when I open the result after downloading from the web, the value from setting the row to repeat at top disappears.

I think OpenTBS does not provide an option for this - I've tried searching Google, but there are no results.

How can I set print title in excel using OpenTBS, if it's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30238100/1768779) recently when trying to set the same property through OpenXML.

There appears to be two ways to set "print titles" in Excel. The first is through the page layout window, as you've tried, which saves the property into the `SpreadsheetPrintingParts` XML object, which appears to be related the the machine it was written on. I had no luck trying to set this with OpenXML.

The other option, is to define a Named Range using the name `Print_Titles`. To do this, open your template in Excel, select the relevant row, and name it "Print_Titles" in the top left box which shows the row reference. (Save it - if you close and reopen and reselect the row, you should see the "Print_Titles" name is retained in that box.) I haven't tried this, however, I imagine it would be more likely to be preserved in an OpenTBS template than the `SpreadsheetPrintingParts` object. Let us know how it goes!

[image: Print_Titles]

Comment: setting pint_title by :
[page layout -> print title -> sheet -> setting row to repeat at top]
or
block area cell and type/set Print_Titles is the same. 
after templates generate by opentbs the print title setting is disappear.

Comment: @Rifai - Are you writing into the title cells with OpenTBS?